# An async function UserTest calls and awaits an async function GetUser but the value returned by GetUser is undefined

Tags: typescript, async-await, undefined

Code for `GetUser.tsx` is:

```
import { auth } from "../lib/firebase";

var currentUserID: string | undefined;

async function GetUser() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
        const userValue = user;
        currentUserID = user?.uid;
        console.log("in get user and user id = " + currentUserID);
        console.log("in get user and user value = " + userValue);
    });

    return currentUserID;
}
export default GetUser;
```

Code for `UserTest.tsx` is:

```
import GetUser from "./GetUser";

async function UserTest() {
    const userUID = await GetUser(); 
    console.log("UserTest after await and userUID = " + userUID);

    return <div>To Do...</div>;
}
UserTest();
export default UserTest;
```

So UserTest calls GetUser and expects a Promise but even after the await in GetUser() to resolve the Promise into a value the value of userUID is still undefined. The console log from GetUser has values for currentUserID and userValue. But the console log from UserTest shows userUID as undefined even though its value is being assigned from an "await' expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: If this is supposed to be a React app then there appears to be a variety of things wrong in the code shown.  I suspect you'd want something like a custom hook around the firebase auth (if they don't provide one) which internally tracks the state of the current auth.  Components could then re-render from state changes in that hook.